# HIghCharts bar chart renders columns on top of each other

Tags: highcharts

I am having an issue with rendering a basic bar chart using HighCharts. I am using two series, both with a x and y value. I am storing date in the x and a number in the y. When I runt he code the columns are rendered on top of each other. I used a very similar code with an older version of HighCharts and the columns were displaying fine. These problems started occurring more recently.

Any help is much appreciated.

The code is very basic and I made it available at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Tp8U/) as well.

Comment: As an aside I would recommend you make your series in order from smallest to largest x. Sort it by date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I suspected when I wrote the comment.
Please make sure your time series is sorted by time. See http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/P7YWU/. Same data, just sorted.